# How to form a query that only selects the first entry from two linked tables?

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have two tables, one for collecting info about measurements (table1) and one for the different "stations" (table2) that do these measurements. Meaning table1 has a table2.id ref in it and table2 has a counter field.

Here is the question: Is there a way to find only the 1st measurements in table1 from all "stations" (table2.ids)?

Answer (score 0):

use `group by` to get single measurement row for each station.

```
select * from measurements join table stations on stations.id = measurements.sid group by measurements.sid
```

Comment: Ty, this sounds great! Will try.